# I made several attempts to create Tcl variables from file content, always failed. What can it be?

Tags: tcl

I made an outline of a basic example. To simplify the scenario I am facing on time!

To have a reflection of what is happening to me, let's first follow the line of logical reasoning.

Let's go to the Walkthrough:

1 - I create the parent directory:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl
```

2 - Then I create the subdirectories Children:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/A

$ mkdir -p /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/B

$ mkdir -p /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/C
```

3 - Now, I will populate the subdirectories with dummy files:

```
$ touch /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/A/1.png /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/A/2.png /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/A/3.png

$ touch /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/B/1.png /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/B/2.png /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/B/3.png

$ touch /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/C/1.png /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/C/2.png /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/C/3.png
```

4 - Anyway, we can check if everything is ok.

```
$ cd /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl/

$ pwd

$ ls *
```

5 - Verified and confirmed, it's time to start working the script.

```
$ echo "A" > /tmp/.directory

$ DIR=$(cat /tmp/.directory)

$ cd $DIR

$ ls *.*
```

> **NOTE** - "This last step is the main cause of my headache, not in Bash, but in Tcl." _

Ready! The bourn shell operation [`sh`] was a success.

Now, starting from this same line of reasoning. Let's start with the Tcl language [`tclsh`].

---

In this step, you can only follow the flow from the previous step (bash), so as not to create the file among other features. Just let's reuse something done before. Follow:

1º

```
set folder "/tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl"
#Return : /tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl
```

2º

```
% set entry [cd $folder]
```

3º

```
% pwd
#Return : tmp.meLBJzexGc
```

4º

```
% puts [glob -type d $entry *]
#Return : . C B A
```

5º

```
% set file [open "/tmp/.directory"]
#Return : file3
```

6º

```
% set text [read $file]
#Return : A
```

7º

```
 % close $file
```

8º

```
% set view "$text"
#Return : A
```

9º

```
% puts [glob -nocomplain -type f -directory $view -tails *.png]
#Return : ?
```

> You should expect this, but do not enter the directory. I did it on purpose for you to understand or what happens if I create.
>   You will see in the next lines below what happens. Continue..

---

So let's create a variable to get there.

```
% set view [cd $text]
```

Return : couldn't change working directory to "A": no such file or directory

**Tai a big problem!**

How can I go there and check the directory contents if it is giving me this unknown error!

```
% puts [glob -nocomplain -type f -directory $view -tails *.png]
```

If you create a direct insertion of the direct directory name in `glob` without going through this variable that is fed by a file containing the name of that directory. This works, see:

```
% puts [glob -nocomplain -type f -directory A -tails *.png]
#Return: 3.png 2.png 1.png
```

But that's not what I want. I really need this file with the subdirectory name (s).

This file is used every time a widget `button` is pressed, so an "`exec echo "A" > /tmp/.directory`" `command` is triggered according to the letter of the alphabet that corresponds to the name of each group and therefore can be accessed. .

If anyone can explain to me why this is giving error while accessing. Be sure to reply or even comment. Your help will be most welcome!

Comment: The return value from the `cd` command is documented to be the empty string. So your view variable is empty, not "A".

Comment: Are you sure your `text` variable just holds the string `"A"` and nothing else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I advise never using `cd` in scripts because it changes the interpretation of filenames. Instead, it is much simpler in the long run to use fully qualified filenames everywhere.

Secondly, `cd` never returns anything other than the empty string. Don't use the empty string as a filename, it confuses things (and not just Tcl!)

```
set folder "/tmp/tmp.AbiGaIl"

set f [open "/tmp/.directory"]
gets $f dir
close $f

set subfolder [file join $folder $dir]

set files [glob -nocomplain -dir $subfolder -type f *.png]
foreach filename $files {
    puts "found [file tail $filename] in $subfolder :: $filename"
}
```

If you just want the last part of the name of a particular file, use `file tail` when you need it. But keep the full filename around for when you are talking about the file and not just its name: it is just so much more reliable to do so. (If you ever work with GUI apps, this is vital: you don't have anything like the control over the initial directory there.)

That advice *also* applies (with different syntax) to every other programming language you might use for this task.